# asp.net list box item selected

Tags: asp.net, listbox

In an asp.net forms application I want to present a list of documents. The list is manually populated. I want to click on an item (no multiselect) and download the item. Populating the list and the download works fine. My problem is what control to use. Ideally I would like to use the Listview, but I cant figure out how to get it to use a click event. How can I add a click event to the Listview? Or is there a better control to use?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you're trying?  I didn't think ASP Classic even *had* "controls" and "events", it was just VB Script code around HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete working example.Just copy the code as is and make sure you create a folder in your solution called *FilesToDownload* and drop some sample files in it for testing.

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class aaaaa_ListViewWIthDownload : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var file1 = new MyFile { FileName="File 1", FilePath="~/FilesToDownload/File 1.txt" };
        var file2 = new MyFile { FileName = "File 2", FilePath = "~/FilesToDownload/File 2.txt" };
        var file3 = new MyFile { FileName = "File 3", FilePath = "~/FilesToDownload/File 3.txt" };

        var files = new List<MyFile>() { file1, file2, file3 };

        listViewFiles.DataSource = files;
        listViewFiles.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Unnamed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton downloadButton = sender as LinkButton;
        if (downloadButton != null)
        {
            string filePath = downloadButton.CommandArgument;
            this.DownloadFile(filePath);
        }
    }

    private void DownloadFile(string filePath)
    {
        string fileName = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(filePath).Name;

        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.ClearContent();
        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + fileName + ";");
        response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(filePath));
        response.Flush();
        response.End();
    }

}

public class MyFile
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<asp:ListView ID="listViewFiles" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("FileName")%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="Unnamed_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FilePath")%>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

**Output:**

[image: Downloading Files in ASP.NET web forms example]

Comment: Denis your answer is 100% what I was looking for. The documents I am downloading are actually attachments stored in exchange, so I am using a "Response.BinaryWrite" of the attachment content. FilePath is the attachment ID from Exchange. Content type is set to the content type of the attachment. No issues, except the "Response.End" throws a "threading was being aborted error".  Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help you!Please mark as answered if my answer helped you